# How to instantiate different subclasses by string in c++?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

Here are some subclasses that derive from the abstract class:

```cpp
class obj
{
  public:
    virtual std::string type() = 0;
};

class subobj01 : public obj
{
  public:
    std::string type() override
    {
        return "subobj01";
    }
};

class subobj02 : public obj
{
  public:
    std::string type() override
    {
        return "subobj02";
    }
};

class subobj03 : public obj
{
  public:
    std::string type() override
    {
        return "subobj03";
    }
};
```

Now I want to define a function that does the following,

```cpp
// pseudo-code
type create_instance(std::shared_ptr<obj> o)
{
    if (o->type() == "subobj01")
        return std::make_shared<subobj01>();
    else if (o->type() == "subobj02")
        return std::make_shared<subobj02>();
    else if (o->type() == "subobj03")
        return std::make_shared<subobj03>();
}
```

I don't know if this can be achieved using template metaprogramming. Thanks!

---

**Update:**
I know I can use `std::dynamic_pointer_cast` to convert pointers manually.

In fact, `obj` and `subobjxxx` are defined by third-party libraries (I shouldn't modify them). I just want to implement a wrapper to do the pointer conversion **automatically**, without manually specifying the type.

Comment: `auto` will fail because the return types of different branches diffeer, but you can specify that your function returns a `std::shared_ptr<obj>` and rely on the fact that `std::shared_ptr<subobj01>` et al implicitly convert to `std::shared_ptr<obj>` (assuming you make them publically inherit from the abstract class instead of privately)

Comment: Adding a virtual `clone` method to each class would probably be simpler. Otherwise fixing the return type is all you need to do to make your function work i think

Comment: If you didn't do it with smart pointers, but used plain non-owning pointers (like `obj* o` and `return new subobj1;`), how would you solve it then? What would your return-type be then? What makes you think it would be different when using smart pointers?

Comment: Simply use the abstract factory pattern with a map. Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71635517/c-polymorphism-factory-how-to-build-function-object-from-its-string-name-and-m/71636312#71636312

Comment: Why do you want to create a fresh object of the same type as an existing object? In what real-life situation is this useful?

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to replace `type` in the return type with `std::shared_ptr<obj>` which all the `std::shared_ptr<subobjXX>` can be converted to implicitly since the `subobjXX` inherit from `obj`.

But you can avoid the whole string matching effort by simply declaring `create_instance` a pure virtual member function of `obj` and overriding it in each subclass to return `std::make_shared<subobjXX>()`. With the help of CRTP the repeated definitions in each subclass can even be avoided.

Then you can call it on an object `o` of type `std::shared_ptr<obj>` or `std::shared_ptr<subclassXX>` (assuming the `shared_ptr` is not empty) simply as `o->create_instance()` instead of `create_instance(o)`.

Comment: Huh? After `std::shared_ptr<obj> o;` there is no object in `o` on which a virtual function could be invoked.

Comment: I know I can use `std::dynamic_pointer_cast` to convert pointers manually.
In fact, `obj` and `subobjxxx` are defined by third-party libraries (I shouldn't modify it). I just want to implement a wrapper to do the pointer conversion automatically, without having to specify the type manually.

Comment: @j6t I didn't intend that to be a declaration and "after" to mean immediately after that in a list of statements. I just wanted to say what type `o` is supposed to be. I clarified it.

Comment: @J.WKang I don't understand. You don't need any `dynamic_pointer_cast` or anything. If you don't expect the function to return `std::shared_ptr<obj>`, what type would you expect the result of a call like `create_instance(o)` to have? Which of the subclasses is stored in the pointer is a runtime property, but types of expressions need to be determined statically at compile-time.